# What DownloadManager intent to use when the user cancels the download from their notifications?

Tags: android

See above.

I need to dismiss a dialog when the user cancels a download from their notification bar. What does DownloadManager broadcast when that happens?

[image]

Comment: Where do we see?

Comment: Do you mean the download?

Comment: It is explained here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14088174/5582190

Comment: Do you attach any image?

Comment: Uploaded an image of what I mean by cancelling a download in the notifications. @Jaymin I want to know whether the download has been cancelled. The answer seems to be about removing a download from the queue.

Comment: @J.Chan, `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` broadcast is sent not only for completed download, but it is also sent when you cancel the download.

Comment: @Jaymin Thank you. I checked it out and it does receive an intent from DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE. How to check that the download has been cancelled though? The COLUMN_STATUS still indicate STATUS_RUNNING in the receiver.

Comment: Additionally, the log says that "Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR" and the DownloadManager finishes with "Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY". Should I be checking for those? Is there no direct way of checking whether the user cancels a download?

Comment: You can mange by keeping track of all download files and status or you can integrate the 3rd party library which provides all the use-cases that you want.